# PhpDoc annotations: how to 'point' a variable just in one place

Tags: php, phpdoc

```
class SomeClass {

    /** @var AdaptedClass */
    private $adaptor;

    public function __construct() {
        $adaptorClassName = 'AdaptedClass';

        if (class_exists($adaptorClassName)) {
            $this->adaptor = new $adaptorClassName();
        }
  }
```

Hello! Consider the code above. Simple question: is it possible with phpdoc annotations to 'declare' `AdaptedClass` just in one place? Because now it is in two places: in `@var` and in `$adaptorClassName` and if I change it to be something else - I need to change it in two places here.

Comment: You theorically can with reflection on docblock. It would be way over engineering imo. Why not using an interface?

Comment: Why not inject a class instance in the constructor (and of course not inject it, if the class does not exist)?